# Spring 5.3 deprecates CciTemplate

Tags: jca, cci

Spring 5.3 deprecates class CciTemplate, CciDaoSupport, etc:

```
* @deprecated as of 5.3, in favor of specific data access APIs
 * (or native CCI usage if there is no alternative)
 */
@Deprecated
public class CciTemplate implements CciOperations
```

What alternatives are there ?

Comment: It looks like you will have to use the specific API's now, such as Java Transaction API (JTA), JDBC, Hibernate, and the Java Persistence API (JPA)